# Laravel forgot password function doesn't work

Tags: laravel, forgot-password

I have the default config for this since I'm new to Laravel. When I type the mail in /password/reset view it keeps loading till a timeout error is thrown in /password/email view.

Comment: Please show us your Laravel log

Comment: Probably because you don't set the email stuff information in your `.env` file ?

Comment: add your code here

Comment: Well, after some tries configuring .env and mail.php I managed to get the "We have e-mailed your password reset link!" message, but I get nothing in the inbox